# Why do I get a Nokogiri crash and MemoryError: negative re-allocation size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, rack

I've got a crawler that runs fine locally, but when I run it on a XL EC2 instance, I'm getting a `MemoryError: negative re-allocation size` error.  I've searched the web but can't find anything helpful.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we were getting this error because of our disk was full.