# NoMemoryError: negative re-allocation size while unzipping large XML (.gz) files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zlib

In my Rails application, I wanted to gunzip a group of XML files I downloaded from an FTP server.

Each XML file is associated with a merchant and consists of product details. I am trying to unzip each file using `GzipReader` and then want to parse it with `Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document`.

The "gz" files are of variable sizes and I was able to unzip files of sizes around 140 MB, but when the file is larger (~428 MB), the application is throwing this error:

```
cj_unzipping.rb:10:in `read': negative re-allocation size (NoMemoryError)
from cj_unzipping.rb:10:in `block in <main>'
```

I read "[Why do I get a Nokogiri crash and MemoryError: negative re-allocation size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838475/why-do-i-get-a-nokogiri-crash-and-memoryerror-negative-re-allocation-size)", but there is lot of space left in my disk.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zlib'

Zlib::GzipReader.open("/home/elmiya/project/mywebapp/cj1.xml.gz") { |gz|
  g = File.new("/home/elmiya/project/mywebapp/cj1.xml", "w")
  g.write(gz.read)
  g.close()
}
```

the line `gz.read` creates the issue.

I'm running:

```
Rails version: 4.0.2
Ruby version: 2.0.0p643
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Why is this a Nokogiri or XML problem? Your code doesn't reference Nokogiri at all, you just want to eventually parse XML using Nokogiri. Don't throw every tag you can think of into a question, only the ones that are directly involved.